# How to delete data on page_load event if literal3.text="N"?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I want to delete record on page load event ... using vb.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Literal3.Text = "N" Then
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                con.ConnectionString = "My connection string"
                con.Open()
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM a1_ticket WHERE Ticket_no='" & Literal3.Text & "'"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
                cmd = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM a1_holds WHERE Ticket_no='" & Literal3.Text & "'", con)
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah looks good..so... what's the problem.. ??

Comment: What's the error you are getting

Comment: No problem and no error and not working

Comment: set a breakpoint on if stement and see if literal3.text is `N` or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text`

Put a `try{} catch`
and see if you catch an Exception?

use a SQL Query Like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("DELETE FROM a1_ticket WHERE Ticket_no='{0}'" Literal3.Text.ToString())
```

and Debug the `cmd.CommandText` and see what the String outputs as.

is `Ticket_no` a `VARCHAR` or `INT?`

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind...

- You're overloading Literal3 - using the field both as a flag to control the flow into the delete statement, and also as the number of the ticket to be deleted.
- Is the ticket number really a string?  If not, then why are you quoting it within the delete statement?
- you should really [parameterise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) the query to avoid [injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)